# Should I use save/load or export/import for my application using Docker? And an additional uncertainty

Tags: docker

Without hardly any knowledge of Docker, I made a program that remotely manages images and containers for many PCs (robotic platforms) on a local network.  All of the PCs are the same with a lightweight OS that supports docker natively.  The goal is now that an image has been made which has all of the drivers and packages necessary to create 'missions' for the robot, I can use any computer with docker to start a container from that image, program a mission, then save the container and send it to any of the PCs which are robotic platforms.  Then I see myself running the container and just starting the mission.

My question is this: currently my image is 2.4 GB as a base (and will possibly grow).  Should I use **save/load** or **import/export**?  Reading how save holds onto the layers, export sounds better for storage.

Then my generic docker uncertainty is can I mix/match (save and import) or (export and load)?

Super bonus docker question: I'd like to check a file to see if it's a valid image (saved or exported).  Is there a simple offset I can check for a few bytes that would confirm it is a docker image?  I couldn't find docker header file information online.

Thanks!

Comment: I'ld like to answer "no". That a bad practice to create image using `save` or `export`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `load` and `import` is that `load` is used to import a saved docker image with its meta data, while `import` is used to create a new image from a tar ball that contains the file system.

For `save` and `export`, `save` will export a local docker image along with all its meta data, while `export` is used to export a **container**'s file system as a tar ball.

Generally manually editing a container is considered bad practice. Ideally you would aim for a few base images, some external source code you can easily maintain via git and a build process that assembles the final image through a Dockerfile in each project. Then push the image to a docker registry.

If you go for the "bad practice" route, I would recommend to use [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) on the edited container to create a new image then either push/pull or save/load.

Comment: Well if that's the case, I'll have to talk to my client how they plan on devising their missions.  They gave the impression they wanted to work in the container then just transfer the container, but I do see now it'd be a much cleaner and more efficient process to handle it through a Dockerfile.  I'd imagine they could tarball their source files and create a Dockerfile ADD line to move it in there.  Then decompressing and executing would be trivial.  Does that sound more appropriate in your opinion?

Comment: It all depends on your client's requirements, but generally speaking, yes. For development it's also common to just mount the source files into a container to avoid constant image rebuilds.